# How to Catch an Exception During Compilation

Tags: java, exception, compilation

Hi I am a beginner programmer to the point that I am just learning about exceptions in Java, and what I have learned about them has been self taught, not yet covered in class. I am looking to have a simple method which only accepts 4 specific strings as input, and otherwise does not work. what I have right now looks like this:

```
public void setRating(String rating){
    switch (rating){
        case "G":
        case "PG":
        case "R":
        case "NR":  this.rating = rating;
                    break;
        default:    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but if I then write invalid code such as:

```
setRating("invalid");
```

my code compiles and does not send an error message until I try to run it.

My question is this: Is there a way to write this so that it is caught at compilation? It seems to me that down the road, allowing invalid code to compile like this could cause a headache for someone using my code. Not sure if this is a stupid question or not, or even something I should be worried about, but any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It will not be a headache, because exceptions should be handled by the person implementing your method.

Comment: You should add a `throws` declaration to your method definition. `public void setRating(String rating) throws IllegalArgumentException{ ... }` this way, your compiler should worn you that the `setRating` method throws an exception.

Comment: @Titus Since `IllegalArgumentException` is a `RuntimeException` it is not necessary.

Comment: It's a bad idea to declare `throws SomeRuntimeException` because that's not the purpose of runtime exceptions. Runtime exceptions are for programmer mistakes. Checked exceptions, those that do not extend `RuntimeException`, are for method signatures.

Comment: Exceptions are only thrown at runtime. The compiler issues errors (not `Error`s), not exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), so that the allowable values are defined in a way that the compiler understands.

```
public enum Rating {
    G, PG, R, NR
}
```

---

```
public void setRating(Rating rating){
    this.rating = rating;
}
```

---

```
setRating(Rating.G);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about exceptions in [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). But in a nutshell the answer to your question *"How to Catch an Exception During Compilation*" is *"there is no way to do it"*. Exceptions are thrown only in runtime, notifying you that something went wrong during program execution.

So if you want to limit the list of available values that your `setRating()` method could accept follow *4castle's* answer.

Answer (score -1):

All Checked Exception are catched in compilation time, but as you see in your code,

```
        default:    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

It is an unchecked Exception (Runtime), so the compiler says, you know what? i think you know what to do, if you want to catch it is ok, if not it is ok for me IDC.

As you see in your switch, if the value is diferrent from

```
case "G":
        case "PG":
        case "R":
        case "NR"
```

You trhow a RuntimeException so Is ok if you caught it or not, If you want to caught it you must know this :

[image]

Now you can change your code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        DefaultClass def = new DefaultClass();
        try{
            def.setRating("ds");

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("hEY I GOT AN ERROR");
        }
        System.out.println(def.rating);


    }
      String rating;

    public  void setRating(String rating){
        switch (rating){
            case "G":
            case "PG":
            case "R":
            case "NR":  this.rating = rating;
                        break;
            default:    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

So I caught the Exception.

Or Use a Enum, so you just let the user to use The options you made, not options that are not allow.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but checked exceptions are not caught at compile time. They can't be, because they are only thrown at run time. Checked exceptions are _checked_ at compile time to ensure proper handling, which is why they're called "checked". But they are not _caught_ except at run time. There's also no such thing as a "checked `Throwable`".

Comment: Never declare `throws Exception`, and basically never `catch (Exception ...)`.

Comment: To elaborate, normally exception interactions should be specific. Not necessarily the most specific, but it makes sense to throw `IllegalArgumentException` or catch `IOException`; even the type informs you of what happened. `Exception` itself is handled somewhat specially, though it isn't a `RuntimeException`. Plus it's really too general to use directly. It's meant as a root class and parent occasionally to a custom exception.